# Is this function entire on the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

That is, $f(z) = \overline{z} = x - iy$

I know that a function is differentiable at $z = z_0$ iff the partial with respect to $x$ is equal to $-i$ times the partial with respect to $y$  (that is to say, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied).  If I take my partials here I get $1$ wrt $x$ and $i$ wrt $y$.  So if I write my Cauchy-Riemann equation I get:

$1 = -i(i) = 1$

Which works for all values of $z$, so is the function entire?

I have a feeling this is wrong.

Comment: This function is the first example one meets of a non-analytic function...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner if we were to replace every $z$ with $\bar{z}$ in any analytic function, would it no longer be analytic?

Comment: It would not be analytic if $ \frac{d}{d\overline{z}} \ f(\overline{z}) \ \neq \ 0 \ $ .

Comment: I see, so only for constant functions it holds true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the definition

$$\lim_{z\to a}{\overline{z-a}\over z-a}=-2\arg(z-a)$$

which means it depends on the path taken, so the limit does not exist unless $a=0$.

Comment: That makes sense, but how did you get the argument function?  When I converted into polar I got $e^{i(\phi_1 - \phi_2)}$, is that the same thing?

Comment: @EdiMadi yes. Remember that $\overline{w}$ has the opposite argument of $w$, that's how I got $-2$ times the argument.

Comment: I see, so basically it reduces to $e^{-2i\phi_2}$, if I keep it in my form.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For any complex function, you can think as a real function of the variables $x$ and $y$. You can then change to variables $z$ and $\bar{z}$. The function is holomorphic (on an open set) if it is differentiable as a real function in two variables and does not depend on $\bar{z}$, that is, the partial derivative with respect to $\bar{z}$ is zero. This is the meaning of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Moreover, $f(z)=\bar{z}$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.